# Kotlin sort array by value in range

Tags: android, algorithm, sorting, kotlin, comparable

Let's have a `class Player(val position: Int, val time: Float)` and we want to sort an array or list of `players` by `position`. If some of these `players` have the same `position` after first sorting, we want to sort them by `time` in groups. By group I mean set of `players` with the same position.

I know about

`list.sortedWith(compareBy<Foo> { it.a }.thenByDescending { it.b }.thenBy { it.c })`

But of course it does not solve this case.

Is there any smart way in Kotlin to achieve this simple task? We can sort it manually by checking positions and swapping items, but I wonder if Kotlin has something to say in this case.

Comment: Why doesn't `sortedWith` solve this case?

Comment: You should make your question clearer: What kind of data structure do you have, do you want to have this one sorted always, i.e. whenever a new element is added it's supposed to be sorted in at the appropriate position or do you want to have a function which sorts on demand? What data structure do you need then?

Comment: yes, i wasn't specific about this. i wanted kotlin to showoff with case like this and converting array to map and then back to array is just not desired solution. i thought about some tricks like parallel sorting or even in place with some extra predicates, but you are right tho, we can sort it by converting list to map and then back again. i marked your answer correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first sort by `position` and `time` and then group by `time` with standard Kotlin functionality.

### Example

```
data class Player(val position: Int, val time: Float)

val p1 = Player(1, 10f)
val plys = arrayOf(p1, p1.copy(position = 3),
        p1.copy(time = 0f), p1.copy(time = 20f),
        p1.copy(position = 2), p1.copy(position = 2, time = 20f))

val groupBy = plys.sortedWith(compareBy(Player::position, Player::time))
                  .groupBy { it.position }
```

### Description

1. sort the `Array` by the `Player`'s `position` and `time` with [`sortedWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) + [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html)
2. group it by the `Player`'s `position`

### Result

The result is a `Map<Int,List<Player>`, which in the example looks like this:

```
    {
     1=[Player(position=1, time=0.0), Player(position=1, time=10.0), Player(position=1, time=20.0)], 
     2=[Player(position=2, time=10.0), Player(position=2, time=20.0)],
     3=[Player(position=3, time=10.0)]
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know about `groupBy{}`, but it results with a map instead of list as you wrote yourself. It changes structure of keeping `players` and in my case it is a deal breaker.

Comment: maps are easily converted to lists using `toList()` ... this should be marked the correct answer, or the OP should clarify the desired result

Comment: well it is not desired to sort an array through converting it to map and then back to array, but i wasn't specific about this, so i mark this answer correct