# Display n number of images in a ScrollView / RecyclerView using Glide with Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, comparator, android-glide

I'm new to Kotlin Language so i got stuck in middle of my project.

**Problem 1:**

I have an array of image files from my local directory ( n... no. of files ) but i'm not able to display all files in the image view using "For Loop" because Kotlin For loop is totally different, i can't able to understand it properly.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.cambarkro.kotlintest

import android.net.Uri
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import java.io.File
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val linearLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearLayoutid)
    val imageView = ImageView(this)

    val path  = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/" )
    val statusFilesAry = path.listFiles() // Storing files in array

    if(path.exists())
    {
        if(statusFilesAry != null && statusFilesAry.size > 0 )
        {
            for(statusFile in statusFilesAry)
            {
                Glide
                        .with(this)
                        .load(statusFile)
                        .into(imageView)

                //linearLayout.addView(imageView)
            }
            linearLayout.addView(imageView)
        }


        Toast.makeText(this, "path found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "path Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

}
```

Above code just showing one image.

**Problem 2:**

From the above MainActivity.kt code, there is a variable "statusFilesAry" which contains an array of all image files. I need to sort those array elements by lastmodified.

In java, we could use Comparator to sort it but in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified Code for kotlin

```
if (path.exists())
    {
        if (statusFilesAry != null && statusFilesAry.size > 0)
        {
            val ll = LinearLayout(this)
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)
            for(statusFile in statusFilesAry)
            {
                val imageView = ImageView(this)
                val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
                imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)
                Glide
                        .with(this)
                        .load(statusFile)
                        .into(imageView)
                ll.addView(imageView)
            }
            val scrollView = ScrollView(this)
            scrollView.setFillViewport(true)
            scrollView.addView(ll)
            linearLayout.addView(scrollView)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change below java code how you want  in kotlin

```
        if(path.exists())
        {
            if(statusFilesAry != null && statusFilesAry.size > 0 )
            {
              LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
          ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
          ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                for(statusFile : statusFilesAry)
                {
                  ImageView imageView = ImageView(youractivity.this)
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                        Glide
                            .with(this)
                            .load(statusFile)
                            .into(imageView)

                    ll.addView(imageView)
                }
             ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
             scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
             scrollView.addView(ll);
                linearLayout.addView(scrollView)
            }
```

[Kotlin sort array by value in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903816/kotlin-sort-array-by-value-in-range)

https://grokonez.com/kotlin/kotlin-array-sort-sortby-sortwith

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer its helps me a lot and working fine.One more question i have, how to implement this in a recycler view ? because scroll view taking lot of memory usage, if you have time please help me with this, _Thank_ _you_ _very_ _much_.

Comment: look at this example....try your self if have any issues let me know https://android.jlelse.eu/using-recyclerview-in-android-kotlin-722991e86bf3